# SQL query to pull all customers, SKUs and customer pricing with quantity discount from epicor/prophet 21 to sync with magento

Tags: magento

I am trying to figure out the correct SQL query to pull out all customers, pricing and SKUs from Epicor / Prophet 21.

We are trying to sync P21 with our magento store and are looking to have customers see their own pricing when they login.

I am looking for what tables the data is stored in within P21.

Any help our guidance will be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Pricing in P21 is very complex. You have to investigate your SQL Server P21 database and specifically experiment with their stored procedure named p21_price_engine.

It takes more than 20 parameters but many are optional and depend on your P21 setup/environment. A good way to try and understand it is to take a look at the code and turn on their debugging statements which prints intermediary results.

Break it down section by section and run this independently so you understand how it is building the result step by step.

If you just want to know a valid query, an idea is to use the SQL Server Profiler to capture inputs from P21 so you can see how the Order Entry is calling it.

If you start looking hard enough, there are other functions and stored procedures that have some pricing functions. It took me a long time to reverse engineer how this all worked. However you probably won't be able to directly call this stored procedure from your PHP/Magento site. I wrote a new site using a Zend Framework / PHP system and decided to write my own stored procedure in SQL Server to provide pricing. It checks contract pricing first, returns price breaks on quantity with a different format that usual in p21_price_engine, and then provide fallback pricing when encountering bad prices/data which unfortunately is pretty common with our very diverse product catalog.